# How show the run date on the Test Runs Summary widget on JIRA Dashboard

Tags: jira-xray

I have added the Test Runs Summary xray widget to my JIRA Dashboard.

The results are shown - but there is no timestamp at all, so you have no idea when the run was executed. Is there any way to show the run time?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[Test Runs Summary gadget](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Test+Runs+Summary+Gadget)" aggregates test runs, showing thereforece the counts only; it's not a list of Test Runs. Currently, this gadget doesn't provide drill-down/expand capabilities. If this is something that may be useful to you, please reach out [Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) asking for this improvement. I'm not sure exactly how that would be implemented, but that is a question that the PO has to analyze.

Meanwhile, uou should use the Test Run List gadget instead, and include the "Started on" and "Finished on" field on the gadget configuration.

[image: test runs list gadget configuration]

[image: test runs list gadget]